# Apex Up - Error: Cannot find module 'debug'

Tags: node.js, deployment

The error persists after I CLI enter `up stack delete` and also when I CLI enter `up` in an alternative directory that I know worked previously. Error also persists if I revert inconsequential changes to a prior working state.

Changing the name field in the `up.json` file results in a successful deploy in the alternate directory! But something about deploying with the same alternate name from my problem directory causes the issue again.

`npm i -S debug` does not help.

Has anyone else experienced and resolved this problem somehow?

**UPDATE:** Getting closer. By commenting things in and out I've got the error

> "Error: Cannot find module './src/resolvers'"

From line:

```
var resolvers_1 = require("./src/resolvers");
```

Changing to:

```
var resolvers_1 = require("./resolvers");
```

fixes the single import issue, but not the remaining...

I'd move the index.js file to the src directory and keep a flat file structure... but I have complex reasons I can't do that.

**"apex logs" of issue:**

> Aug 31st 05:58:27pm INFO staging 88776d6 initializing
>
> Aug 31st 05:58:27pm INFO staging 88776d6 starting app: PORT=33461 command=node dist/index.js
>
> Aug 31st 05:58:27pm INFO staging 88776d6 started app
>
> Aug 31st 05:58:27pm INFO staging 88776d6 waiting for app to listen on PORT
>
> Aug 31st 05:58:28pm ERRO staging 88776d6 module.js:549
>
> Aug 31st 05:58:28pm ERRO staging 88776d6     throw err;
>
> Aug 31st 05:58:28pm ERRO staging 88776d6     ^
>
> Aug 31st 05:58:28pm ERRO staging 88776d6
>
> Aug 31st 05:58:28pm ERRO staging 88776d6 Error: Cannot find module 'debug'
>
> Aug 31st 05:58:28pm ERRO staging 88776d6     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:547:15)
>
> Aug 31st 05:58:28pm ERRO staging 88776d6     at Function.Module._load (module.js:474:25)
>
> Aug 31st 05:58:28pm ERRO staging 88776d6     at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
>
> Aug 31st 05:58:28pm ERRO staging 88776d6     at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
>
> Aug 31st 05:58:28pm ERRO staging 88776d6     at Object. (/var/task/node_modules/finalhandler/index.js:14:13)
>
> Aug 31st 05:58:28pm ERRO staging 88776d6     at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
>
> Aug 31st 05:58:28pm ERRO staging 88776d6     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
>
> Aug 31st 05:58:28pm ERRO staging 88776d6     at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
>
> Aug 31st 05:58:28pm ERRO staging 88776d6     at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
>
> Aug 31st 05:58:28pm ERRO staging 88776d6     at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
>
> Aug 31st 05:58:42pm FATA staging 88776d6 error creating handler: waiting for http://127.0.0.1:33461 to be in listening state: timed out after 15s: name=clowdfuncserver type=server
>
> Aug 31st 05:58:42pm INFO 2018-09-01T00:58:42.959Z  22adf73a-ad82-11e8-9c6c-79de5ffabc3f    Error: read ECONNRESET
>       at _errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
>       at Pipe.onread (net.js:628:25)

Comment: Still getting the same type of import error for node modules even when I compile and upload a single-file webpack bundle. Seems like the new manifestation would be a different cause though.

Answer (score 0):

Despite additional issues blocking me, this webpack configuration worked for me:

```
// webpack.config.js

module.exports = {
  entry: "./src/index.ts",
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        exclude: [/node_modules/],
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        use: "ts-loader"
      },
      {
        include: /node_modules/,
        test: /\.mjs$/,
        type: "javascript/auto"
      }
    ]
  },
  node: false,
  output: {
    filename: "index.js",
    path: path.join(__dirname, "dist")
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".tsx", ".ts", ".js", ".mjs"]
  },
  target: "node"
};
```